# How does the ancient Jewish Wedding tradition foreshadow Christ and the church?

Tags: life-of-jesus, ecclesiology, jews, jewish-culture, typology

I remember something about the ancient Jewish Wedding Ceremony being a foreshadowing of Christ and the Church.  Kay Arthur authored a novel that illustrates this idea, entitled *[With an Everlasting Love](http://books.google.com.au/books/about/With_an_Everlasting_Love.html?id=2A8fFSfhdSEC&redir_esc=y)*.

So, what are the specifics of the ancient Jewish Wedding ceremony and how do they foreshadow Christ and the Church?

Comment: This answer has some of what you are looking for: [What Place was Jesus going to prepare](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/10236)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As I understand it [all Jewish brides are stolen](http://www.khouse.org/articles/2011/987), they are snatched away.

> All Jewish brides were said to be “stolen, caught up, or snatched up
>   by surprise.” The bride was then led to the groom’s house by a wedding
>   procession of women carrying lighted lamps, similar to the Parable of
>   the Ten Virgins that we will explore in next month’s Personal Update.

Traditionally the Father of the Bride and the Father of the groom along with the groom negotiate terms for the brides hand and the covenant is sealed with wine. The groom then goes off to prepare a place in his father's house for his bride.  The groom then comes in an evening unannounced and snatches his bride away.

Bride and groom retreat to the bridal chamber prepared by the groom and the couple consummate the marriage and share their bridal week together. They then come out of the bridal chamber to celebrate the marriage feast with friends and family.

Parallels:

- Christ sealed His covenant for His bride with His own blood depicted by wine
- Some believe Christ will steal His bride at the rapture
- Some believe that Christ like the groom is preparing a place for us as promised in John 14:2
- Some believe the bridal week is likened to the seven year tribulation where the bride will be with the groom
- Some believe the marriage feast will be like the millennial reign of Christ

Comment: Some sources from Jewish literature would benefit your answer.

Comment: If you linked to a source for the bride stealing and such I will upvote.

Comment: http://store.levitt.com/  Zola Levitt Ministries (Christian Love Story)

Answer (score 0):

The Bride also has responsibilities in the marriage contract. She must learn the things her husband wants her to do as well as maintain her purity for the wedding night. 
There is a good book that explains all of this called Lost in Translation Vol. 1: Rediscovering the Hebrew Roots of Our Faith by John Klein and Adam Spears. It goes into great detail on the Hebrew marriage ceremony and it’s relation to the Messiah.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  This next has nothing to do with the quality of your answer, it's just standard to help new visitors avoid misunderstanding the site (as I did at first.)  As a new visitor, I'd recommend checking out the following two posts, which are meant to help newcomers "learn the ropes": [the help page](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help) and [How we are different than other sites?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites)